# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firefoxSample')

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

I am working on a React.js project and when I run it on localhost, I encounter the following error message in Chrome browser: 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firefoxSample')'. This error only occurs in Chrome - I tried running the project on Firefox and Microsoft Edge, and everything worked fine. Interestingly, other members of my team do not experience this error, so I suspect the issue may be specific to Chrome. Can someone please help me with this issue?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONDZm.png)

i tried to clear chrome cache , but that  didn't work .

Comment: edit your question to provide a [mre]. also read [ask], especially the part about not posting images of code.

Answer (score 9):

I turned off the Chrome extension 'OrangeMonkey'.

Comment: Thank you ,I disable orangeMonkey and that work for me to .

Answer (score 1):

If you have the savefrom.net extension remove that from your chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but within Angular project. Turned off extensions and the error disappeared

Answer (score 0):

I turned off the Chrome extension called 'OrangeMonkey'. Now it is fine for me.